# Copy docker image between repositories

Tags: docker

I have 2 private docker repositories. Is any way how can I copy one image from one repository to the second one?

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can pull the image, tag it and push it to the new registry.

Example:

```sh
docker pull old-registry/app:some_tag
docker tag old-registry/app:some_tag new-registry/app:some_tag
docker push new-registry/app:some_tag
```

Comment: This is not a full answer since it will match host architecture and move only specific variation to new registry.

Answer (score 23):

Can be done with https://github.com/containers/skopeo

Example for the README:

```
skopeo copy docker://quay.io/buildah/stable docker://registry.internal.company.com/buildah
```

The advantage is that Skopeo does not require Docker on the machine it runs on.

Comment: The disadvantage is that Skopeo is a third-party app that requires additional installation

Answer (score 0):

Found this question when looking for a way to copy an image from local docker registry on `host-a` to local docker registry on `host-b`. If you have SSH access to `host-b` this should work:

```bash
user@host-a:~$ docker image save "repository:tag" | ssh host-b "docker image load"
```