# How to retain docker-image after release-candidate build for future push to prod registry

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In our release-candidate pipeline to our QA (think "stage") environment, we are using a vmImage to build our docker-container and then pushing it to our Non-Prod registry.

```
pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

steps:
  - task: pseudo-code: ## get everything prepped for buildAndPush
  - task: Docker@2
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: "Our Non-Prod Registroy"
      repository: "apps/app-name"
      command: "buildAndPush"
      Dockerfile: "**/Dockerfile"
      tags: |
        $(Build.SourceBranchName)
```

These are release-candidates. Once the code is approved for release, we want to push the same container to our Production registry; however, we can't figure out how to do it in this framework.  Seems like we have only two options:

- rebuild it in a different run of the pipeline later which will push it to our Production registry
- push every release-candidate container to our Production registry

I don't like either of these options. What I want is a way to retain the container somewhere, and then to push it to the our Production registry when we decide that we want to release it.

How would we do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually

1. Push docker image to your non-production registry
2. Once your it is approved for the release (I don't know what exactly you mean by saying this in terms on your pipeline) you can (Please check this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976188/copy-docker-image-between-repositories))

> You can pull the image, tag it and push it to the new registry.

```
docker pull old-registry/app
docker tag old-registry/app new-registry/app
docker push new-registry/app
```

You can also take a look [here](https://medium.com/@pjbgf/moving-docker-images-from-one-container-registry-to-another-2f1f1631dc49) where is described above case.

Comment: so, we are using the "Docker@2" plugin to manage our tasks, and it doesn't include a 'pull' command. is there another way to use docker in a pipeline where you just make commands? maybe an example of what this code would look like in yaml?