# How to copy artifacts between projects in Google Artifact Registry

Tags: google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry, docker-repository, container-image

Previously using Container Registry one could copy a container between projects using this [method](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#copying_images_to_a_new_registry)

However I am unable to get this working using Artifact Registry. If I try

```
gcloud artifacts docker tags add \
        us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/source-proj/my-repo/my-image:latest \
        us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/dest-proj/my-repo/my-image:latest
```

It gives the error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.artifacts.docker.tags.add) Image us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/source-proj/my-repo/my-image
does not match image us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/dest-proj/my-repo/my-image
```

I have searched and can not find any examples or documentation on how to do this.

Comment: Maybe the way to think about it is that each project has its own registry and then use:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49976188/copy-docker-image-between-repositories

Comment: Yes that is a work-around and what I have done for the time-being, I'm just hoping there is a convienient method like there previously was

Comment: @rossco Can you refer to the link : https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/reference/docker-api and https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling Is it helpful?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using
`gcrane cp us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/source-proj/my-repo/my-image:latest us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/dest-proj/my-repo/my-image:latest`

Comment: How can the above command be run since source-proj and dest-proj belong to different accounts and at a time GCP allows you to login into One account .

Is there any way to download all the artifactory images from one account and push to another project account

Comment: @shirishsahu - An IAM identity (user and service account) can be authorized for more than one project at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **gcrane** tool to copy images in Artifact Registry.

For example, the following command copies image `my-image:latest` from the repository `my-repo` in the project `source-proj` to the repository `my-repo` in another project called `dest-proj`.

```
gcrane cp \
    us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/source-proj/my-repo/my-image:latest \
    us-east4-docker.pkg.dev/dest-proj/my-repo/my-image:latest
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/copy-images) is the link to the Google Cloud official documentation.

Comment: This works beautifuly! I found the go installation found on the [github README](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/blob/main/cmd/gcrane/README.md) to work better on my Mac.

Comment: How can the above command be run since source-proj and dest-proj belong to different accounts and at a time GCP allows you to login into One account .

Is there any way to download all the artifactory images from one account and push to another project account